# Are 7555 inputs protected internally by diodes?

Tags: timer, 555

I've tested the inputs of a 7555 with a diode tester and I could read a 0.7V/0.6V drop between each input and GND and each input and VCC. Something that suggests that they are protected for over/under voltage by internal diodes like this

[image: internal diodes]

These diodes do not appear on the internal schematic that is provide on page 5 of the  datasheet
https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/icm7555-icm7556-datasheet

Am I correct in assuming that these diodes are present but have not made it in the internal schematics? or is there a way for the input current (say RESET pin) to somehow find a path to VCC and GND (given the correct polarisation of the input) via the NMOS transistors?

Comment: All CMOS ICs are. Internal schematics don't show you what's in the IC. Just a conceptualization so you know what's happening.

Comment: @DKNguyen ahh right. I suppose this also protects any input that is left floating from being damaged by static discharge.

Comment: It's meant for protection during assembly. Often not strong enough for the end product.

Comment: Usually you can find a pseudo-schematic somewhere on the data sheet or on the manufacturer's web site that says "all inputs are protected by a circuit similar to this."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s generally true of many CMOS circuits (some, such as those  with high-voltage tolerant inputs are exceptions). Usually the circuit is a bit more complex than just diodes as you can find by testing it (more like diodes with a few hundred ohms in series, at a minimum). Here is what they look like for inputs on the [CD4007](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4007ub.pdf?ts=1628362344215) (D2 is kind of a distributed diode):

[image]

Usually exceeding the voltage by a bit is permissible **if** the current is limited to some number of mA before the potentially destructive SCR [latch-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch-up) described in the [datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/icm7555-icm7556-datasheet) Note #4 is triggered, but, unfortunately, the datasheet offers no guidance on how much current is permissible. (Normal operation is not guaranteed under such conditions).
For example, the [CD4001B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4001b.pdf?ts=1628442519957) has an absolute maximum input current of +/-10mA for one input at a time only.

[image]

This is a bit of a cop-out. Note that the timing capacitor will often be discharged via the protection network as the supply voltage falls, violating the alleged absolute-maximum voltage at those pin(s). Adding a diode is possible, but anything that limits the voltage to +300mV compared to the supply will be very, very leaky in relation to the 20pA input current.

One would expect the device to be more sensitive to ESD-induced latchup at higher supply voltages, and in fact the similar TLC555 indicates that..

> Using only passive components to protect the TLC555 with a single 15-V
> supply is not recommended because the higher voltage allows for an
> unacceptable amount of current to flow through the device

It will likely also be more sensitive at higher ambient temperatures where the gain of the parasitic SCR structure is higher.

Note that the parasitic SCR structure mentioned in the datasheet is **not** unique to the 7555 but rather is present in virtually all CMOS devices (not on silicon-on-sapphire, but that's rather rare). More modern devices are designed to have higher tolerance to currents through the protection networks and substrate diodes which trigger the SCR self-destruct (think of it as the gate trigger current), the first CMOS gates were extremely prone to latch-up. Some modern gates can withstand 100mA spikes without latching up. 74HC04, for example, allows 20mA.

It's anyone's guess what the 7555 is capable of, but maybe 1mA is safe enough. Maybe.

Comment: "Maybe" is the operative word here.  For a high-rel application like a space mission, "maybe" isn't going to cut it.  To pass muster, such designs usually require resistors in series with those input so that you can guarantee that the input current will never exceed the specified maximum value.

Comment: And I think that input protection you showed is more or less standard across the industry.  I know our internal silicon foundry uses the same input protection scheme.

Comment: @SteveSh my point though is that there is **no** specified maximum current in the datasheet, so to be 100% safe you cannot use any of the usual circuits. At some point you’ll turn them off and the 300mV will be exceeded. If there is a big filter cap on the power supply then latchup could destroy the chip. It doesn’t, usually.

Comment: @SteveSh My understanding is that modern input protection cells are fairly proprietary and various trade secrets and patents are involved to get the required characteristics. The 4007 is ca. 1969 so not very modern.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful, on Intersil's data sheet it states this:

> NOTES:.
> 4. Due to the SCR structure inherent in the CMOS process used to fabricate these devices, connecting any terminal to a voltage greater than V+ +0.3V
> or less than V- -0.3V may cause destructive latch-up. For this reason it is recommended that no inputs from external sources not operating from the
> same power supply be applied to the device before its power supply is established. In multiple supply systems, the supply of the ICM7555 and
> ICM7556 must be turned on first.

From that statement I would treat them as if there is no protection. Also keep your impedances as high as possible, they tell you in the data sheet that will reduce operating current.

Other vendors may manufacture their parts differently and may have protection. Read the data sheet that is published for the parts you are using.

Comment: +1 for actually reading the datasheet instead of guessing.

Comment: Thanks, I had to pick one, there are several versions that have the intersil name and others from different manufacturers, not all had that note. That is why I stated "Read the data sheet that is published for the parts you are using."